# Writing an Iterator for a Custom Class

Tags: c++, iterator

I'll preface this by saying I am mostly working off of examples written by others, so my understanding of template classes and friend classes is subpar. I am trying to write a circular list class:

```
#ifndef CIRCLIST_H
#define CIRCLIST_H
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Node
{
    public:
        Node() : next(NULL), prev(NULL) {}
        Node(const T& v) : value(v), next(NULL), prev(NULL) {}

        T value;
        Node<T>* next;
        Node<T>* prev;
};

template <class T> class circList; //Forward declaration

template <class T>
class circIterator
{    
    public:
        circIterator() : ptr(NULL) {}
        ~circIterator() {}

        T& operator*() { return ptr->value; }

        circIterator<T> & operator=(const circIterator<T> & old) { ptr = old.ptr; return *this; }
        circIterator<T> & operator++() { ptr = ptr->next; return *this; }
        circIterator<T> & operator--() { ptr = ptr->prev; return *this; }

        friend class circList<T>;
        friend bool operator==(const circIterator<T>& l, const circIterator<T>& r) { return l.ptr == r.ptr; }
        friend bool operator!=(const circIterator<T>& l, const circIterator<T>& r) { return l.ptr != r.ptr; }

   private: 
       Node<T>* ptr;
};


template <class T>
class circList
{
    //class circIterator;

    public:
        circList() : entry(NULL), vsize(0) {}
        ~circList() {}

        unsigned int size() const {return size;}

        typename circList<T>::template circIterator<T> add(T const& v, circIterator<T> itr);

   private:
       Node<T>* entry;
       unsigned int vsize;   
};

template <class T>
typename circList<T>::template circIterator<T> circList<T>::add(T const& v, circIterator<T> itr)
{...}
```

When I write a simple main.cpp which simply declares a circList, I get the error:

`error: no class template named 'circIterator' in 'class circList<int>'`

The error references the last line, where the add function is implemented. What exactly does this mean? Does it mean that somewhere I have to code how an circIterator should "belong" to an circList? I really have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that in `circList<T>::template` you are trying to access an identifier `template` (which is a keyword) that is not set for the class.

Just define the function as:

```
template <class T>
circIterator<T> circList<T>::add(T const& v, circIterator<T> itr) {...}
```

and declare it as:

```
circIterator<T> add(T const& v, circIterator<T> itr);
```

And [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69978a40f18a784f) is the working example.